# How to change material of indivudal objects in THREE.js without the use of separate Meshes?

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh, 3d-modelling

We have created a PCB Viewer in THREE.js and now we are looking to add some selection functionality to it. This is not a difficult task and I already have this functionality working though I am facing some performance issues. As we want all features of the PCB Layers (shapes) to be individually clickable and selectable (the colors change when selected) I figured each shape need their own THREE.js Mesh, so that we can control their Materials individually. Sure enough, it works as expected but of course it has massive performance issues as now, instead of having one combined mesh for all shapes on a PCB layer we have THOUSANDS.

I understand that having a lot of Meshes will degrade the performance. This is obviously true. Does anyone have any tips on how this could be done in a more performance efficient manner? For now it is enough for us to just change the colors of the indivudal shapes when they are clicked. Before my code changes we had all shapes in the same geometry on the same THREE Mesh. Can I somehow, in any way, keep this more simple structure but still manipulate inidivudal shapes/objects separately? To me it sounds far fetched but I am not too experienced in THREE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up with the following solution:

- I render "simple" meshes to my real scene, where a lot of objects are in the same geometries (objects sharing the same Material mostly)
- I keep a "virtual scene" which I never render, on which I perform raycasting and check for intersections. In the virtual scene I have actual separate meshes for the individual objects.
- When I find an intersection in the virtual scene, I clone that mesh object and add it to the real scene with the "selection material". I also apply a small offset to it so that it is slightly bigger than the original, to prevent z-fighting
- When objects are deselected, I remove the selection objects from the real scene. I use user attributes to identify which ones they are. Each selection object also has a "back link" to the mesh from where it was cloned in the virtual scene. This way I can also check if I already have a selection of a certain object.
- To know "Where" to the real scene to add my object (to which group - we have quite an advanced tree structure...) I also keep a user attribute in the virtual scene that "points to" (by id) the parent in the real world, to which I would add the selection object IF it is selected.

Hope this makes sense and that it will help someone else too

Answer (score 1):

The cost is not primarily the number of *meshes*, but the number of *draw calls*. Each draw call consists of a paired chunk of geometry (represented by THREE.Geometry) and a shader program (represented by THREE.Material). While three.js does allow multiple materials per mesh, the number of draw calls remains the same, so that won't solve your problem by itself.

What you probably need, instead, is to manipulate conceptual 'objects' without having separate THREE.Mesh and THREE.Material instances for each. For example, if you know the range of vertices selected, you can modify the vertex colors for that object to highlight it, or modify the vertex positions to move it.

It's also possible to store an original object ID as a vertex attribute for each object, and then you could use a custom shader material to apply certain changes in your material for different objects.

Example:

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Yea I think I need to try to use the range of vertices  and try to modify those.. I cannot use the exact way of the example as our thousands of objects could really all be different, meaning I cannot re-use a single simple box for each selection draw. I will try to cache the ranges of indices before merging the geometries and somehow use that to change the color.. Not 100% sure on how to do this yet though as we currently use raycaster to get the object clicked and this seems to rely on separate meshes.. So I guess maybe I need to use some of the logic from the ex

Comment: THREE.Raycaster will also return the index of the selected face, if you need to use that to look up the object. But the raycaster will be faster on many small objects than a single large one, so it might be worth keeping both representations, or use a raycaster like three-mesh-bvh that can handle large objects well.

Comment: Okay yea thanks. I think I will test what works out best. I kind of have it working now actually but for some reason my clicks find the id of the shape on the backside of our board, not front and vice versa. So if clicking from the front, it will find stuff on the back and clicking from the front will find stuff on the front. Kind of like it finds the "last" mesh on those coordinates... I would like to flip this behaviour obviously. Any ideas?